# Save Terminal Output command on OSX

Tags: macos, command-line, mac, terminal, osx-el-capitan

It is simple question but couldn't find the answer, I found and tried `tee output.txt` and `system_profiler > output.txt` but no success, they save blank text file. How do I save my terminal output with command in terminal on OSX El Capitan?

Comment: Your command should work fine.  Please see my tested answer.

Comment: Yes you are right, I waited like 1-2 minutes and text file is not blank anymore but it doesn't save the output, it saves application's detail stuff. I am speaking of `system_profiler > output.txt`

Comment: "system_profiler > output.txt"  has the exact same effect as "system_profiler", except saved to a file.   "system_profiler -xml > output.txt" will print in an xml format that is sometimes useful but not what you are looking for.  Can you show me the difference you get between "system_profiler" and the file from:  "system_profiler > output.txt"?  I'm using exactly the same syntax as you.   I get exactly the same thing, the expected result.

Comment: There is something missing. Either you are cancelling the command mid-way, or you are not satisfied with the original output of "system_profiler" as it is without printing. Whether printing to file or not, the result is massive. If you only want to limit the results to the first paragraph, then use "system_profiler --timout 5 > output.txt" and it will stop itself. That is not a printing issue. Please explain how the result in the file is different from the result on screen.  CONFIRM YOU ARE NOT SENDING SIGKILL [CTRL-C] etc....  because then we are not doing the same thing at all.

Comment: Yes I do CTRL-C. When I do it there is no problem when I save terminal output manually, why would it be a problem to do it with command?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `command` is the command you want to run, you can pipe it's output into the output.txt using:

```
$ command > output.txt
```

or

```
$ command | tee output.txt
```

If this doesn't hell it may be because the output is not printed on `stdout` but on `stderr`. The pipe `>` is implicit writing for `1>` which means "pipe `stdout` to ...".
If you want to pipe `stderr` into the file too, you can use

```
$ command >output.txt 2>&1
```

This pipes all the output of `stderr` to the file-descriptor `1` (=`stdout`) which in turn is piped into the text file.

Comment: I don't have Mac but every shell I've ever seen does explicit (i.e. other than pipe) redirections in the order given, so you need `>output 2>&1`. Alternatively in bash you can use `&>output` or `>&output` to do both at once; see the man page.

Comment: I only use OSX in a Virtual Machine, my primary is Linux -- and every shell I've used works with both ways.

Comment: Not the two Linuxes I currently use: on Ubuntu(14) with `bash` or `dash`, doing `cat bad 2>&1 >output` sends the error message to the tty and nothing to the file; on CentOS(6) with `bash` or `dash` or `ksh93` the same, and with `tcsh` it gives an error `Ambiguous output redirection`. Could you give me an example I can download (on x86-64) or connect to that works for that form?

Comment: Still blank text file and no success, it may be an el capitan issue? Are you on latest el capitan?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I just noticed I only use `command 2>&1 | tee output.txt` which does work this way around, but you're right, for `>` it doesn't. I never noticed O.o

Comment: @hzleonardo I just fired up ElCapitan 10.11.5 and yes it works, you just need to give it some time. You do not even need the stderr-redirection except you want to get info about devices that didn't respond etc.
For me it took quite some time: `time system_profiler > out.txt 2> err.txt  23.36s user 39.51s system 96% cpu 1:04.97 total`, so perhaps just wait ...

Answer (score 1):

Syntex:

```
$command > /output/file/location
```

Example: suppose you want to list out all files and directories of /home/jackson and save its result to /home/jackson/list.txt so command will be--

```
$ls /home/jackson > /home/jackson/list.txt
```

but remember if file /home/jackson/list.txt is already exist and contain information, then previous command will erase your previous information and write your command output. so that if you dont want to erase your previous information use ">>" instead of ">". so your command will be.

```
$ls /home/jackson >> /home/jackson/list.txt
```

Hope that will help..

Comment: Am I the only one who is doing something wrong? I see these commands everywhere but it doesn't work for me, I waited, still blank text file. Are you el capitan 10.11.5?

Answer (score 0):

## Q. How do I save my terminal output with command in terminal on OSX El Capitan?

## A. Simply give your computer enough time to complete that particular command (1m30s or so).

Your command should run without issue.

---

On my mac the command:

```
system_profiler > output.txt
```

..  Takes about 1m30s to complete.

---

System profiler also has formatting options and a time-limit if desired.

```
system_profiler -xml -timeout 3 > textfile.xml
cat ./textfile.xml
```

Reference:

```
man system_profiler
system_profiler -usage
```

Result (with nl to count the line numbers).  This file is the same as the command and is about 52000 lines.

system_profiler > output.txt
nl output.txt

```
     1  Accessibility:

     2      Accessibility Information:

     3        Cursor Magnification: Off
     4        Display: Black on White
     5        Flash Screen: Off
     6        Mouse Keys: Off
     7        Slow Keys: Off
     8        Sticky Keys: Off
     9        VoiceOver: Off
    10        Zoom Mode: Full Screen
...
...

 51937            Wake On Wireless: Supported
 51938            AirDrop: Supported, Channel 0
 51939            Status: Off
```

Comment: Yes same result for me too which I don't want. I am trying to do "Export Text As" in shell menu with a command. When I do it manually it's ok, only print's from terminal in the text file in a second but with commands, blank file or this output in text after 1-2 minutes.